# Painting a cube using N different colors?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

> In how many different ways can a cube be painted by using N different colors of 
>   paint?

Note that this question is not same to [Painting the faces of a cube with distinct colours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/painting-the-faces-of-a-cube-with-distinct-colours) as the colours here may not be distinct (i.e. used many times). For [Painting the faces of a cube with distinct colours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/painting-the-faces-of-a-cube-with-distinct-colours), we must have $N>=6$, and the result will be:

$$\binom{n}{6}(5)(3!)$$

Can anyone help how to tackle such problem?

Comment: Isn't the title what you want to ask? You are asking the case $N=3$, right?

Comment: @mathlove Fixed the problem. I want to know is there a generalization solution for any N. Thanks.

Comment: One approach is to use [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Comment: @mathlove And $N>=6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem

Specifically, under Examples -> Colored cubes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the answer is correct, but here's some of my idea:
if we are painting a cube with $6$ distinct colours.
fixing one of the faces, the face on the opposite side has $5$ colour choices
using the circular arrangement for the rest of the $4$ sides we have $3!$ ways.
In total, we have $5\times6=30$ ways.

Now if we have $n$ colours, after fixing the first face the opposite face has $(n-1)$ colour choices. There are now $(n-2)$ colours left to choose and for the four faces left we might choose $4$ colours from the $(n-2)$ colours and do the circular arrangements again.

In total, we have $(n-1)\times\binom{n-2}{4}\times3!$ ways.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).