# Possibilities to decorate a cube with different patterns

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I have the following problem:

> You're trying to decorate a cube. How many essentially different cubes are there, if there are six different symmetric patterns to choose from for every side? Also, how many essentially different cubes are there, if it's the same situation, except for the fact that one of them can only be used once?

For the first problem I found the solution, by using the formula: $$\frac{1}{24}(1*x^6+3*2*x^3+3*x^4+6*x^3+4*2*x^2)$$ for x being the amount of patterns to choose from for every side. So for x=6 there should be 2226 possibilities. But for the second problem, I have no clue how to solve it. There are two cases:

1) This particular pattern is not on the cube. So there are according to the formula 800 possibilities.

2) The pattern is there exactly once. But how can I find the possible decorations in that case?

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is the pattern symmetric?  That is, should you take into account rotations of the pattern by 90 or 180 or270 degrees?

Comment: Yes, the patterns are all symmetric. I'll edit it.

Comment: So you could think of it as having 6 different colors, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Painting the faces of a cube with distinct colours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/painting-the-faces-of-a-cube-with-distinct-colours)

Comment: In my problem the colours could appear more than once. So there could be one side blue and the other five could be red.