# Number of ways to color cube sides.

Tags: finite-groups

How many ways can cube sides be colored by 4 types of color? I need something, not exactly the answer, maybe just formulas or theory I need. Up to 4 different colors. no, rotation does not change.

Comment: All $4$ colours or up to $4$?  Do rotations of the cube which look the same count as different?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64857/painting-the-faces-of-a-cube-with-distinct-colours?rq=1

Comment: up to 4 different colors. no, rotation does not change the cube colors

Comment: Ive seen the topic you linked, but my problem is more complex since my cube can be colored using only one color

Comment: @VladTrotsenko so repeat the process from the link 4 times: for 1 color, for 2 colors, for 3 colors and for 4 colors

Comment: @Holo actually it wont work since cube cannot be colored by 4 different colors because there are not enough sides! The question linked has a formula for number of colors higher than 5 because another way this question would be impossible to answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a case for [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), AKA Polya counting theory. The Wikipedia article explains exactly your problem in detail, albeit with three colors instead of four. Now translate the described procedure to your situation.